# How do I conditionally display a list within a column in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to conditionally display something in a Column in flutter.

Here's what I currently have:

```dart
Container(
                height: blockSizeVertical * 99,
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 28, horizontal: 26),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildCloseButton(context),
                    _buildTopCopy(context),
                    _buildEmailField(context),
                    _buildPasswordField(context),
                    _buildLoginButton(context),
                    _buildForgotPasswordLink(),
                  ],
                )));
```

Within this column, I want to conditionally display something while leaving `_buildCloseButton` alone: something like this:

```dart
            child: Container(
                height: blockSizeVertical * 99,
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 28, horizontal: 26),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildCloseButton(context),
                    _buildTopCopy(context), --------------
                    _buildEmailField(context),           |
                    _buildPasswordField(context),        | -> // I want to conditionally swap these out
                    _buildLoginButton(context),          |
                    _buildForgotPasswordLink(),-----------
                  ],
                )))
```

What I've tried was something like this (but doesn't work)

```dart
  List<Widget> _buildLoginScreen() {
    return [
      _buildTopCopy(context),
      _buildEmailField(context),
      _buildPasswordField(context),
      _buildLoginButton(context),
      _buildForgotPasswordLink(),
    ];
  }

// ....

Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildCloseButton(context),
                    _forgetPasswordScreen
                        ? ForgotPassword()
                        : _buildLoginScreen(),
                  ],
                )
```

However this doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Edit: *I am on Dart 2.13.4*

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator with your condition:

```dart
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildCloseButton(context),
                    _forgetPasswordScreen
                        ? ForgotPassword() : 
                     ...[
                    _buildTopCopy(context), 
                    _buildEmailField(context),  
                    _buildPasswordField(context), 
                    _buildLoginButton(context),          
                    _buildForgotPasswordLink(),]
                  ],
```

Edit:

Try a different approach since you can't use the spread operator:

```dart
                  children: <Widget>[
            _buildCloseButton(context),
            if(_forgottenPasswordScreen)
             ForgotPassword(),
            if (!_forgetPasswordScreen)
              for (var widget in [
                _buildTopCopy(context),
                _buildEmailField(context),
                _buildPasswordField(context),
                _buildLoginButton(context),
                _buildForgotPasswordLink(),
              ])
                widget ],
```

Comment: I totally would if I was on Dart 2.3! I am on 2.13.

Comment: @nyphur Check the edit

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code?

```
 Widget _buildConditionTrue() {
    return Column(
       children: <Widget>[
      _buildTopCopy(context),
      _buildEmailField(context),
      _buildPasswordField(context),
      _buildLoginButton(context),
      _buildForgotPasswordLink(),
    ]);
  }

 Widget _buildConditionFalse() {
    return Column(
       children: <Widget>[
      _buildForgotPasswordLink(),
      _buildEmailField(context),
      _buildPasswordField(context),
      _buildLoginButton(context),
      _buildTopCopy(context),
      ]);
  }


Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
                _buildCloseButton(context),
                condition? _buildConditionTrue() : _buildConditionFalse(),
      ])
```